# Kubernetes setup for docker container - kubectl get minions failing

Tags: kubernetes

I am setting up Kubernetes with flannel following the instructions from

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config.md
http://www.severalnines.com/blog/installing-kubernetes-cluster-minions-centos7-manage-pods-services

I am blocked at the following two steps, and unable to locate troubleshooting steps. I am running this on master node.

> kubectl get minions
>   Error: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1beta3/minions: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused

Is this related to to the flannel network or should it give the minion information on the master node.

> etcdctl mk /coreos.com/network/config '{"Network":"172.17.0.0/16"}'
>   Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379

Where is the port 2379 specified and how do I troubleshoot the sync step to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the errors went away when I restarted the etcd service

> > sudo systemctl start etcd
> >     systemctl status etcd
> >      Active: active (running)

I am now not getting the errors.

However, the command > >kubectl get minions 
is not giving any output. I am looking for way to debug this, as I am expecting it to list two other nodes.

I followed the steps with a clean machine, and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an issue with ETCD. Are you sure you have ETCD cluster up and running?  How did you configure your ETCD cluster?

Comment: Thanks yes - there was an issue with the etcd cluster, and I did respond after I sorted this out.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago Minions were renamed to Nodes, so you should use `kubectl get nodes` instead.

Comment: kubectl get nodes and kubectl get minions are both supported currently.